# Getting the fractional part of a float without using modf()

Tags: c++, c, math, bit-manipulation

I'm developing for a platform without a math library, so I need to build my own tools. My current way of getting the fraction is to convert the float to fixed point (multiply with (float)0xFFFF, cast to int), get only the lower part (mask with 0xFFFF) and convert it back to a float again.

However, the imprecision is killing me. I'm using my Frac() and InvFrac() functions to draw an anti-aliased line. Using `modf` I get a perfectly smooth line. With my own method pixels start jumping around due to precision loss.

This is my code:

```
const float fp_amount = (float)(0xFFFF);
const float fp_amount_inv = 1.f / fp_amount;

inline float Frac(float a_X)
{
    return ((int)(a_X * fp_amount) & 0xFFFF) * fp_amount_inv;
}

inline float Frac(float a_X)
{
    return (0xFFFF - (int)(a_X * fp_amount) & 0xFFFF) * fp_amount_inv;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't fp_amount be 0x10000 instead of 0xFFFF?

Comment: Holy crap. Make it an answer so I can accept it! You just fixed my entire accuracy problem!

Comment: Why hasn't anyone edited the original code if the comment fixed it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want the part after the decimal right?  You don't need it actually in a fraction (integer numerator and denominator)?

So we have some number, say `3.14159` and we want to end up with just `0.14159`. Assuming our number is stored in `float f;`, we can do this:

```
f = f-(long)f;
```

Which, if we insert our number, works like this:

```
0.14159 = 3.14159 - 3;
```

What this does is remove the whole number portion of the float leaving only the decimal portion.  When you convert the float to a long, it drops the decimal portion. Then when you subtract that from your original float, you're left with *only* the decimal portion. We need to use a long here because of the size of the `float` type (8 bytes on most systems).  An integer (only 4 bytes on many systems) isn't necessarily large enough to cover the same range of numbers as a `float`, but a `long` should be.

Comment: An if... then... else... in a math function as often used as this? My cache, it weeps!

Comment: This is wrong when `f` is negative. (You're adding two negative numbers.) You don't need the `if` at all: `f = f - (int) f`.  If `f` is negative it'll be subtracting a negative int that's rounded toward zero.

Comment: Also, you're assuming that the integer portion of the float fits in an int.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks, psyched myself out with the negative part.  And right you are about the float/integer thing.

Comment: Oh well. This answer is both the easiest to implement and the fastest (about 20% faster than my method). Accepted!

Comment: Is it possible that you give a bit more explanation @DanielBingham ?

Comment: Sure.  long is an integer type, meaning it has no fractional (after the decimal point) component.  When you cast your float to a long, it just drops everything after the decimal.  When you then subtract the casted long from your original float, what you have left is only the fractional part.  The whole numbers have been removed.

Comment: `(long)f;` fails when `f` is much outside the `long` range.  `(long long)f;` extends the the range but still the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

As I suspected, `modf` does not use any arithmetic *per se* -- it's all shifts and masks, take a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20121030234640/http://www.raspberryginger.com/jbailey/minix/html/modf_8c-source.html). Can't you use the same ideas on your platform?

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend taking a look at how modf is implemented on the systems you use today. Check out uClibc's version.

http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libm/s_modf.c

(For legal reasons, it appears to be BSD licensed, but you'd obviously want to double check)

Some of the macros are defined [here](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libm/math_private.h).

Comment: Why all the bit shifting, is really that much of a speed gain?  Or does my little int conversion trick have some issue I'm missing?

Comment: @Daniel Bingham: likely the latter. Floats may not be encoded in the way you think on the platform you're using, so your masks may be off. @sharth: your link relies on some macros, and I'm having trouble finding them. Can you try your luck and find definitions for EXTRACT_WORDS, INSERT_WORDS, and GET_HIGH_WORD?

Comment: Int to float is fine. Float to int is horribly slow.

Answer (score 5):

There's a bug in your constants.  You're basically trying to do a left shift of the number by 16 bits, mask off everything but the lower bits, then right shift by 16 bits again.  Shifting is the same as multiplying by a power of 2, but you're not using a power of 2 - you're using 0xFFFF, which is off by 1. Replacing this with 0x10000 will make the formula work as intended.

Comment: Too bad the original poster didn't edit his answer, if this does, in fact, correct the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completly sure, but I think that what you are doing is wrong, since you are only considering the mantissa and forgetting the exponent completely.

You need to use the exponent to shift the value in the mantissa to find the actual integer part.

For a description of the storage mechanism of 32bit floats, take a look [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why go to floating point at all for your line drawing?  You could just stick to your fixed point version and use an integer/fixed point based line drawing routine instead - Bresenham's comes to mind.  While this version isn't aliased, I know there are others that are.

[Bresenham's line drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm)

Comment: For anti-aliased lines see [Wu Lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like maybe you want this.

```
float f = something;
float fractionalPart = f - floor(f);
```

Comment: `floor` is also slower than a cast.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is assuming that there are 16 bits in the fractional part (and as Mark Ransom notes, that means you should shift by 16 bits, i.e. multiply by by 0x1000). That might not be true. The exponent is what determines how many bit there are in the fractional part.

To put this in a formula, your method works by calculating `(x modf 1.0)` as `((x << 16) mod 1<<16) >> 16`, and it's that hardcoded 16 which should depend on the exponent - the exact replacement depends on your float format.

Answer (score 0):

```
double frac(double val)
{
    return val - trunc(val);
}

// frac(1.0) = 1.0 - 1.0 = 0.0 correct
// frac(-1.0) = -1.0 - -1.0 = 0.0 correct
// frac(1.4) = 1.4 - 1.0 = 0.4 correct
// frac(-1.4) = -1.4 - -1.0 = -0.4 correct
```

Simple and works for -ve and +ve

Answer (score -2):

If you can use the standard library, `fmod(x, 1)` does it:

```c
#include <math.h>

fmod(1.42, 1); // => 0.42
fmod(-1.42, 1); // => -0.42
```